# Bootstrap 3: delete confirm dialog box not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found This `bootstrap` function for delete confirm dialog box :

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
            $('body').append('<div id="dataConfirmModal" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dataConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button><h3 id="dataConfirmLabel">Please Confirm</h3></div><div class="modal-body"></div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button><a class="btn btn-primary" id="dataConfirmOK">OK</a></div></div>');
        } 
        $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(this).attr('data-confirm'));
        $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('href', href);
        $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({show:true});
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="delete.cfm" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete?">Delete</a>
```

This worked but `css/JS` style not show dialog box in `bootstrap +3`. how do can i fix this?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hmwQQ/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modal template was changed in bootstrap +3, you need to change the HTML code you append to your body when you open the modal. See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals, the new template is :

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

By the way, there are severals very cool javascript / boostrap plugins to do what you want to do like http://bootboxjs.com/, http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/.